# How to put a certain string into *if* and check if it is a certain word

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I am trying to scan a string and put it in an *if* like so:
(this is just an example part of the whole program)

```
Scanner scan=new Scanner();
System.out.print("Enter the word...");
String a=scan.nextLine();
if (a=="Hi")
System.out.println("Hello!")
Else System.exit(0);
```

So im checking if the user said "Hi" , but it doesnt work like this, I want a way to do it.

I have just started learning java so my questions might seem a little amateur but your answers will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"Hi".equals(a)`, `==` compares identity, not equality.

Also, you should write specifically `"Hi".equals(a)` and not `a.equals("Hi")`, because it won't cause a `NullPointerException`, since `a` might be `null`.

Comment: @JavaIsLife no problem!